# The infinite sum of the division of of two Gamma functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, gamma-function, hypergeometric-function

I would like to calculate the sum of the following convergent series:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\Gamma(k+n+1)(-y)^n}{\Gamma(kN+N+c+n)n!(k+n)(k\alpha+n\alpha+2)}$$

where $k$ is a positive real number and $N$, $c$, and $\alpha$ are positive integers. 
I know the fraction in the above equation without the Gamma functions converges and its sum is already calculated in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445330/probability-distribution-function-expressed-in-terms-of-a-divergent-series?noredirect=1.

I have been looking for ways to find the sum of a convergent series but no use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ratio of consecutive terms is given by

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(n+k)(n\alpha+k\alpha+2)}{(n+kN+c+1)(n+1)(n\alpha+(k+1)\alpha+2)}(-y)$$

Hence the series is given by a [generalized hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function):

$$S=\frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{k(k\alpha+2)\Gamma(kN+c+1)}{}_2F_2\left(k,k+\frac2\alpha;kN+c+1,k+1+\frac2\alpha;-y\right)$$

I wouldn't suspect this reduces much further.

Comment: I've slightly edited my question. will the correct result be the hypergeometric function as ${}_2F_2(k, k+2/\alpha; kN+c+N, k+1+2/\alpha; -y)$ and the gamma function in the denominator $\Gamma(kN+c+N)$?

Answer (score 1):

Just a very minor simplification of @Simply Beautiful Art's result

$$S=\frac{\Gamma (k+1)\,\Gamma \left(k+\frac{2}{\alpha }\right) }{\alpha }\,
   _2\tilde{F}_2\left(k+1,k+\frac{2}{\alpha };k N+c+1,k+1+\frac{2}{\alpha
   };-y\right)$$ using the regularized generalized hypergeometric function.

Comment: Thank  you @ClaudeLeibovici. Is there any way that I can get rid of $c$ in the hypergeometric function?

Comment: @AymenKareem. I do not see any way. Sorry ! Cheers :-)

Comment: I mean can I put $c$ out of the generalized hypergeometric function?